# How do I access the value of the first of multiple uploaded files

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filereader

Currently the code below will display the last uploaded image as a large image after the submit click event.  I want the full-image class to display the first uploaded image instead of the last. Is there a way to display the first uploaded image instead of the last uploaded image. Is there a way to grab the value of the first uploaded image? Any help would be appreciated.

```
HTML 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Gallery App</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="legend">
            Your Images
            <div class="menu-btn">
                <div class="menu-btn__burger"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="upload_form">
            <div class="menu">
                <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
                <input type="file" id="avatar1" name="avatar1" data-thumb='thumbnail-one' required="">
                <button type="submit" id="delete_btn_1">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
                <input type="file" id="avatar2" name="avatar2" data-thumb='thumbnail-two' required="">
                <button type="submit" class="delete_btn">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="avatar">Upload Your Image:</label>
                <input type="file" id="avatar3" name="avatar3" data-thumb='thumbnail-three' required="">
                <button type="submit" class="delete_btn">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div class="submit-container">
                <button type="submit" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box thumbnail-one">
                <img src="https://http.cat/100" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="box thumbnail-two">
                <img src="https://http.cat/405" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="box thumbnail-three">
                <img src="https://http.cat/504" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="full-image">
                <!-- <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> -->
                <img src="https://http.cat/100" id="expandedImg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
jQuery 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
        const uploadForm = document.querySelector('.upload_form')
        let menuOpen = false;
        menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if(!menuOpen) {
                menuBtn.classList.add('open');
                menuOpen = true;
                uploadForm.classList.add('open')
            } else {
                menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
                menuOpen = false;
                uploadForm.classList.remove('open');
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.box').click(function() {
                $('.full-image').html($(this).html());
            });

            $('#delete_btn_1').click(function() {
                $(files).val('');
            });

            $("#submit_btn").on("click", function () {
                var files = $("input[type=file]");
                files.each(function (e) {
                    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                        let thumb = $(this).data('thumb');
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        console.log(thumb);
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            console.log(e);
                            // let imgOne = $(".thumbnail-one img").attr("src", e.target.result);
                            $("." + thumb + " img").attr("src", e.target.result);
                            // I need the line below to access the first uploaded image instead of the last image
                            $('.full-image img').attr("src", e.target.result);      
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                        menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
                        menuOpen = false;
                        uploadForm.classList.remove('open');
                    }
                });
                $(files).val('');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```
CSS 

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6441a5, #2a0845);
    /* background: purple; */
}

.fieldset {
    background-color: lavender;
    border: 10px solid darkblue;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 720px;
}

.legend {
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.fieldset div {
    margin: 10px;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
}

.submit-container {
    /* width: 100%; */
    text-align: right;
}

.container {
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.box {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.full-image {
    width: 580px;
    height: 580px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.col {
    float: right;
}

.full-image img {
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100%; */
}

.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn__burger {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255, 101, 47, .2);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn__burger::before, 
.menu-btn__burger::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255, 101, 47, .2);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn__burger::before {
    transform: translateY(-8px);
}

.menu-btn__burger::after {
    transform: translateY(8px);
}

/* Animation */
/* We are targeting the middle line here */
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger { 
    /*Moves off to the left*/
    transform: translateX(-50px); 
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
} 
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
} 

.upload_form {
    display: none;
    transition: display .7s;
}
.upload_form.open {
    display: block;
    transition: display .7s;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a back-end issue, not a front-end one.

Comment: What about putting a counter inside files.each and run if{.....} only for first value of the counter